# Can't find value of 'input' element in JS

Tags: html

I've been messing with YouTube lately, but the search bar confuses me.

If I search something long, like "a;sldjf;asbybytyeu2430572735gljahflg", then control-f in the DOM, the only reference I can find to the search term is in the page title.
Even when I look at the 'input' element of the search bar, it doesn't have a 'value' property.

**My question is this:** How can the browser display text that doesn't appear anywhere in the DOM? Where is the data stored?

Comment: You *could* do this: `var newElem = document.createElement('div'); newElem.someProperty = {value:0, hidden: 1, someOtherAttribName: 'someTextValueForFun'};` No idea what google is actually doing though. (The attrib names and values I used are entirely arbitrary.)

Comment: The value is there, it's not going to show up on the element if you were to view source or inspect the dom however. `document.querySelector('input#search').value` in the console will show the value of the element.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the URL query string. For example, if I search "dank memes", this is the URL:
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dank+memes

It can be accessed by JavaScript with `window.location.search` which in this case would return `"?search_query=dank+memes"`
But most likely YouTube's JavaScript code does not access it and it is only used to send the information for a GET request to the server. Then the server will display all the needed information.